# I dont need \right, but it gives error

Tags: math-mode

This is my text

[image]

[image]

there is no right bracket and I dont need one

but I get this error

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: You don't need, but TeX does. If you don't want to see the right delimiter you can use `\right.` as TeX is suggesting. It's better to use the `cases` environment though. And please don't post code screenshots.

Comment: Better use `\[ math stuff \]` instead of inline math. And ever use double backslashs or even double double to end a line. TeX will get mad.

Comment: I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful, see http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Courtesy of mathpix we can get with 60\% confidence several alternatives ...
Note it uses the correct $\ right.$ construction
By nature of its one line approach it uses $\backslash\backslash$ however you can remove any surplus by editing them out.

\vspace{1em} 

\[ % per comment by egreg
\left\{%
\begin{array}{l}
{y_{i}-\left\langle\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{i}}\right\rangle- b \leq \epsilon+\zeta_{i}^{*}}\cr % manually replace \linebreak with a carriage return
{\left\langle\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{i}}\right\rangle+ b-y_{i} \leq \epsilon+\zeta_{i}}
\end{array}
\right.% suppress right bracket
\]

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}{y_{i}-\left\langle\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{i}}\right\rangle- b \leq \epsilon+\zeta_{i}^{*}} \\ {\left\langle\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{i}}\right\rangle+ b-y_{i} \leq \epsilon+\zeta_{i}}\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry to say that, \centering will affect all following paragraph which are following the equations, please check...

Comment: Thanks KJO that is what i want

Comment: It's really wrong to use `center` instead of `\[...\]`.

Comment: @KJO -- Reading the text of the example, it is implied that `mathpix` was used to produce the input code, at least the symbol content.  Is this in fact the case?

Comment: @KJO -- Thanks for the information.  The identification of symbols and their "local" positioning is good; I'm not so sure about the choice of environment, but what I see means that it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 6):

Better to use `cases` environment with the usage of `amsmath` and the format is given below:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
.... & ...\\
.... &
\end{cases}
\]
```

If you use this, then the brace and alignment will comes in a nicer way...

Comment: Thanks Mady, appreciate your help

Answer (score 6):

I think the two formulas should be aligned at the `≤` sign and the left `{` is there just for grouping, these are not cases. `aligned` can be perfectly used here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\left\{\begin{aligned}
y_i - \langle\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x_i}\rangle - b &\leq \epsilon+\zeta_i^* \\ 
\langle\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x_i}\rangle + b - y_i &\leq \epsilon+\zeta_i
\end{aligned}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks Yaser. appreciate your help